# Read one character at a time until '*', '%*' or '/*' in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do some text analysis of some SAS code in VBA. I would like to skip comments.

But I can only find a way to read a line at a time using the `Line Input` Statement. But this makes it really hard to avoid comments one the same line as uncommented code, like

```
data _null_; *Comment;
```

**So I would like to know if it is possible to read one character at a time in VBa until a comment start is encounterd?**

Comment: why not just read the line into a string variable then strip off any unwanted comment?

Comment: Because some comments span multiple lines. Like /* code *newline* code */

Comment: Then you have more of a full-fledged parsing problem that is probably best handled by regular expressions applied to the whole file read into a single string.

Comment: How big is the file?  I'd just read the whole thing into a byte array unless it's huge.

Comment: @JohnColeman how would you do that? Can you point me to some examples?

Comment: @Comintern Im a reading several files with about 50 to 500 lines

Answer (score 2):

Since the files are small, one option is to read the entire file into a byte array:

```
Dim handle As Long
Dim bytes() As Byte
Dim path As String

path = "C:\somefile.txt"
handle = FreeFile
Open path For Binary Access Read As handle
ReDim bytes(LOF(handle) - 1&)
Get handle, , bytes
Close handle

Dim char As Variant
For Each char In bytes
    Debug.Print Chr$(char)
Next char
```